# Validate multicolumn property Firebase Database Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a multicolumn index property `filter_active` in this structure.

```
"books": {
   "435085rfddsfiou4r80": {
        "name": "Harry Potter 1"
   }
}

"review": {
   "540398fsdo9043": {
        "filter_active": "true|435085rfddsfiou4r80|false"
        "active": true,
        "archived": false,
        "book_id": "435085rfddsfiou4r80"
        "review": "good book"
   }
}
```

Now I want to use the security rules to validate the `filter_active` property. I need to check if the book exists in the books node. Also the book id in the filter must be equal to the `book_id` in the review object.

There is no such thing as a split method in the Firebase Database Rules. In addition, I tried to create a dynamic regex but I believe this is not possible.

Is there anyway I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the unwanted text in `filter_active` is always a small number of known words or characters, they can be eliminated by repeated use of [replace()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#replacesubstring_replacement).  For example, to eliminate `true`, `false`, and `|`:

```
newData.child('filter_active').val().replace('true','')
    .replace('false','').replace('|','')
```

You can then check for the existence of a book with the resulting key:

```
root.child('books').child(newData.child('filter_active').val()
        .replace('true','').replace('false','').replace('|','')).exists()
```